# How can I insulate the sloped ceiling of an attic room?

Tags: insulation, roof, attic, energy-efficiency

We have a century home. First two floors do well in summer / winter, 3rd floor is always too hot or too cold. The attic was completely uninsulated.

The plan was to use batt insulation on the attic floor but I'm not sure how much it will do given the deep, uninsulated rafter channels leading to the soffit vent. You can get an idea of what I mean by the picture below. The pink areas are what I want to insulate.

The problems:

- Bottom floor of attic only covers a small area
- The rest of the attic roof is a pitched ~9' rafter channel on either side
- This area is over the stairwell / rooms so it does contribute heat / cold
- Only access to insulate the pitches would be shoving down the rafter channel
- Height of the channel is only about 6'' so even R19 would be compressed to leave a 1 1/2'' space

Questions:

1. Is it even worth trying to insulate the pitched area of the roof?  (if that area isn't insulated does the other insulation even make much difference?)
2. What do I do about baffles? There seems to be nothing long enough!
3. If its compressed is it worth trying to go over R-19 in the soffits? Or would blown in be better??
4. Does the ventilation math still apply to 'size of enclosed attic space' or would it be higher given that the soffits are so deep?

I thought of  a few possible solutions to the baffles: Large diameter PVC pipes, maybe cut in half, or cut rigid foam insulation to make custom baffles. Or possibly just using rigid foam insulation though I know its expensive and not very insulating.[image: The pink represents area to be insulated]

Comment: There are already baffles made for this to add insulation and still ventilate the roof deck, so no need to make custom baffles.

Comment: @crip659 The longest I could find were the ADO Provent at 4'. I'm worried that with needing 3 per channel the middle would fall into / get nested under the bottom one since I'd have no way to affix it.

Do you know offhand what the model baffles you mean are?

Comment: Yeah, commercial baffles aren't viable here.

Comment: It's a tough situation if you're not willing to pull down the plaster. If you did that you could increase the height of the rafters to accommodate more insulation plus baffles. What's the sun exposure of the two planes?

Comment: @isherwood The exposure is nearly full sun for one, the other is slightly shaded in the evening.

I simplified the drawing a bit but because of closets / stairs any expanding the rafters would be a major renovation.

Comment: Not sure I understand the baffle problem...is there any reason you can't just use two 4' baffles with a slight overlap, to get nearly 8'?  (You might need 3 baffles with the pitch if your room is st'd 8' height.)